# Insert data to 2 tables php

Tags: php, mysql, database, paypal

ive looked around here and i see similar questions is already answered but i still cant figure this out (as always, im a total noob and need decent explanations)

I have a users.db (userId, mmbrship, mmbrship_date) a few more values but these are the ones i need to update.

Then i have a payments.db ( id, txnid,  payment_amount, payment_status, itemid, createdtime )

In my functions.php i have this code:

```
function updatePayments($data){ 
    global $link;
    if(is_array($data)){                
       $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `payments` (txnid, payment_amount, payment_status, itemid, createdtime) VALUES (
               '".$data['txn_id']."' ,
               '".$data['payment_amount']."' ,
               '".$data['payment_status']."' ,
             '".$data['item_number']."' ,
                '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' 
    )", $link);

    return mysql_insert_id($link);
    }
}
```

I need the values 'itemid' and 'createdtime' from payments.db to be inserted into users.db in 'mmbrship', 'mmbrship_date'

And i need the 'userId' from users.db to be inserted to payments.db
(to connect the user to its purchase)

This is so i can get info from users.db if a member have paid their membership and as it is now the payments.db insert its own id.
So i think if i can just connect these two tables with the userId i might be a step in the right direction...

? Please help :)

Comment: did you check **string** instead of **variable** ? Try this: `INSERT INTO payments (txnid) VALUES ('foo');`, and tell me what happens ?

Comment: 4  foo  0.00    0000-00-00 00:00:00

This was added into the payments.db  (i used the code in phpmyadmin as nothing happened when i edited functions.php :P)

Comment: Is any of these variables coming from user input? If so I recommend checking out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database design is missing a *relationship* between the `user` entity and the `payment` entity.

(In ER modeling terminology, an entity is (roughly) a person, place, thing, concept or event that can be uniquely identified, we need to store information about and is important...)

In order to determine the *cardinality* of the relationship between the entities, we ask a series of questions, for example:

- Can a `user` be related to more than one `payment`?
- Can a `user` be related to zero `payment`s?
- Can a single `payment` be related to more than one `user`?

Based on the answers to those (and similar) questions, we can determine whether the relationship between `user` and `payment` is one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many, and whether it's mandatory or optional.

I suspect that in your model, a `payment` will be related to exactly one `user`. (That is, a given `payment` won't be applied to more than one `user`.) And it will be possible for a given `user` to have zero, one or more `payment`.

If that's the case, that's a one-to-many relationship, and the normative pattern is to store the primary key of the `user` entity as a column on the `payment` table, and to define a foreign key relationship.

e.g.

```
  ALTER TABLE payment ADD `userId` INT UNSIGNED COMMENT 'fk ref user' ;

  ALTER TABLE payment ADD CONSTRAINT FK_payment_user 
    FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES user (userId)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT ;
```

Then, before you insert a row to the `payment` table, you need to figure out which `user` this is related to, and provide a value for the `userId` column to establish the *relationship* between this payment, and the user its related to.

If the `payment` is not related to a `user`, then store a NULL value in the column. If you want *require* that a `payment` be related to a user, then add a `NOT NULL` constraint on the column.

The datatype of the `userId` column in `payment` should match the datatype of the `userId` column in `user`. (In the example above, I just took a guess at the datatype of the `userId` column.)

---

In a relational database, the *relationship* between rows in two different tables is established by storing *common* values in a column of the two tables.

Comment: not sure if i actually understood it all LOL but can i change the 'id' in payments.db to 'userId' and then have the members userId inserted instead of the pointless(?) id its now adding whenever someone purchase a membership?

A member of my site needs to be logged in to purchase membership so it is a userId connected to the script..

At the page where the users can buy their membership i have this in the top of the page:

$id = $_GET['id'];

if (!isset($id)) {

  $id = $_CURRENT_USER->id;

}


Can i use this with the code in functions.php to insert the users id in payments.db?

Comment: A user can have multiple payments in payments.db but in users.db i just need to have 2 values copied over so i can get this info else on my site